# Insert R expressions to word using library rtf

Tags: r, insert, rtf

I wonder if its possible insert R expression or R objects to a word:

example:

```
  data(mtcars)

    (table=head(mtcars,20))
    addParagraph(doc, "\n\n Table cars \n")
    addTable(doc, cbind(rownames(table), table))
    nrow(mtcars)

    In this table we can see that data contain nrow(mtcars) rows
```

But in my word will show:

```
    "In this table we can see that data contain 32 rows"
```

Thanks in advance
R

Comment: `sprintf("In this table ... %d rows", nrow(mtcars))` or `glue::glue("In this table ... {nrow(mtcars)} rows")`

Comment: thanks! glue works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can insert one object into a word. using rtf and glue packages:

```
library(rtf)
library(glue)

data(mtcars)
total=nrow(mtcars)
addText(todo, glue("In this table we can see that data contain {nrow(mtcars)} rows"))
```

my word show:

```
"In this table we can see that data contain 32 rows"
```

Comment: Thanks, in next 2 day i will can do it! ;)